# Schedule selenium to run on a remote server

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, remote-server

I need to run selenium on a remote server since the server doesn't have a screen I'm using PhantomJS as a web driver. this is the code I Have:

```
import time
import os,sys
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
import re
from selenium import webdriver


url = 'https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting'

driver_1 = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver_1.get(url)
content = driver_1.page_source
```

On my computer, it works fine, but after that, I'll open other pages so I need the code keep running for a while.
I'm running the script from the terminal as:

```
python my_script.py
```

And the script will execute on the same terminal from where I'm accessing the server so either I won't be able to disconnect or if a loss the connection the script will stop, how can I handle this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need a read GUI on the server in order to run Selenium with any browser. Selenium can easily run on any server with real browsers like Chrome or Firefox.

Here is some code that should help you make it working:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # Or Firefox()
```

Comment: thanks, that solves one issue, but I'll still have the problem of the connection, how do I avoid to stop the script if I log out of the server?

Comment: `tmux`, `screen` or even `nohup` do a good job solving this issue but I do assume that you will soon want to run these tests under a CI/CD server, like Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks, It Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your script to continue executing even if you lose connection to the server, you can easily do this with terminal software like [Tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) or [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)